# How do I pass an absolute path to the adb command via git bash for windows?

Tags: windows, git, bash, adb, msys

I'm trying to pass a unix style path to the Android adb command using a git bash (msysgit) but the shell is interpreting my path incorrectly. This is what I've tried so far:

```
$ adb push myfile /mnt/sdcard/
failed to copy 'myfile' to 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mnt/sdcard/': No such file or directory

$ adb push myfile "/mnt/sdcard/"
failed to copy 'myfile' to 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mnt/sdcard/': No such file or directory

$ adb push myfile '/mnt/sdcard/'
failed to copy 'myfile' to 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mnt/sdcard/': No such file or directory
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did u try the same in "cmd" (dos-prompt) ? I think it will work there

Comment: @DevJyotiBehera Yes, I did try it with the windows cmd prompt, and it does work, but I was trying to figure out why it was not working with msysgit.  I want to understand how paths and quoting work here.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/11519659/1983854 ? Also, does `ls /mnt/sdcard/` work? To see if it detects the path properly.

Comment: Identical problem here. Gitbash, adb, and push/pull requests. Everything in gitbash seems to work as per standard bash. Curiously, my system even duplicated your problem by prefixing the intended path with `C:/Program Files/Git`. Both solutions below worked for me, so I'm running withe simpler one, ie. `adb push myfile //mnt/sdcard`. Lifesaver!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252767/712605), the MSYS shell is mangling the file name according to [these rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20130226050044/http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion).  According to the mangling rules, the following should work for you:

```
adb push myfile '//mnt\sdcard\'
```

(replace the first slash with two slashes and all remaining slashes with a backslash)

Comment: i was able to do it with all forward-slashes (/)

Comment: U saved my day. Thx.

Comment: I had to use `"//mnt\/sdcard\/"`

Answer (score 9):

`adb push myfile //mnt/sdcard`

linux isn't picky about duplicate `/`s