# Gitbash error, during attach EBS volume to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, git-bash, amazon-ebs

My Jenkins Master working on Windows Server and want to run a shell script with GitBash.
I want to attach the EBS volume to EC2.
When I run "awscli" command in GitBash, I am getting a weird invalid parameter.

```
$ aws ec2 attach-volume  --device /dev/sdf --volume-id vol-0d5736e1b8be30e92  --instance-id i-036540a7e7bbf712b
```

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AttachVolume operation: Value (C:/Program Files/Git/dev/sdf) for parameter device is invalid. C:/Program Files/Git/dev/sdf is not a valid EBS device name.
```

[image]

Comment: that seems like window having trouble with slashes, can you try with `--device "/dev/xvda"`

Comment: Adiii thank you for your comment, but I have tried already the same error. I also tried "\/dev\/xvda".

Comment: $ aws ec2 attach-volume  --device /dev/sdf --volume-id  vol-00817f61e233134fb --instance-id i-036540a7e7bbf712b

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AttachVolume operation: Value (C:/Program Files/Git/dev/sdf) for parameter device is invalid. C:/Program Files/Git/dev/sdf is not a valid EBS device name.

Comment: $ aws ec2 attach-volume  --device \dev\sdf --volume-id  vol-00817f61e233134fb --instance-id i-036540a7e7bbf712b

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AttachVolume operation: Value (devsdf) for parameter device is invalid. devsdf is not a valid EBS device name.

Comment: $ aws ec2 attach-volume  --device \/dev\/sdf --volume-id  vol-00817f61e233134fb --instance-id i-036540a7e7bbf712b

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AttachVolume operation: Value (C:/Program Files/Git/dev/sdf) for parameter device is invalid. C:/Program Files/Git/dev/sdf is not a valid EBS device name.

Comment: $ aws ec2 attach-volume  --device "\/dev\/sdf" --volume-id  vol-00817f61e233134fb --instance-id i-036540a7e7bbf712b

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AttachVolume operation: Value (\/dev\/sdf) for parameter device is invalid. \/dev\/sdf is not a valid EBS device name.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem.

```
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id  vol-00817f61e233134fb --instance-id i-036540a7e7bbf712b  --device '//dev\sdf'
```

response

```
{
    "AttachTime": "2021-02-03T10:08:39.661000+00:00",
    "Device": "/dev/sdf",
    "InstanceId": "i-036540a7e7bbf712b",
    "State": "attaching",
    "VolumeId": "vol-00817f61e233134fb"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344985/how-do-i-pass-an-absolute-path-to-the-adb-command-via-git-bash-for-windows