# How do I pass an Azure resource ID to the az command line in git bash on Windows?

Tags: windows, git-bash, azure-cli

This question is very similar to [How do I pass an absolute path to the adb command via git bash for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344985/how-do-i-pass-an-absolute-path-to-the-adb-command-via-git-bash-for-windows), but the answer to the latter does not work in my case, because `//subscriptions/...` is not a valid Azure resource Id.

Given:

```
VMS=( \
"/subscriptions/d...8/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/cks-master" \
"/subscriptions/d...8/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/cks-worker" \
)
```

I would like to start the VMs using the following command line:

```
az vm start --ids ${VMS[@]}
```

However, it does not work:

```
~$ az vm start --ids ${VMS[@]} | nocolor
ERROR: invalid resource ID: C:/Program Files/Git/subscriptions/d...8/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/cks-master

~$
```

(nocolor is an alias that drops the ansi color sequences using the approach described in https://superuser.com/a/380778/9089)

The aforementioned SO post suggests to prepend another `/`, which works for a file path, but does not work for an Azure resource Id:

```
~$ VMS=( "//subscriptions/d...8/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/cks-master" "//subscriptions/d...8/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/cks-worker" )

~$ az vm start --ids ${VMS[@]} | nocolor
ERROR: invalid resource ID: //subscriptions/d...8/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/cks-master

~$
```

So, what do we do, besides using Powershell or WSL2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` flag at the beginning of the `az cli` command.

In your case:
`MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 az vm start --ids ${VMS[@]}`

See:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_with_git_bash.md#auto-translation-of-resource-ids
- [How to stop MinGW and MSYS from mangling path names given at the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line#34386471)