# adb pull error: cannot create <local_file_path>: No such file or directory

Tags: android, adb

I have some issues with adb that I had never had.
In particular I was trying to pull pics from whatsApp folder but it gives me the error in the title.

Here what I did:

```
D:\Android\media\com.whatsapp>adb pull "/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20211031-WA0050.jpg" "./WhatsApp/Media/Whatsapp Images"

adb: error: cannot create './WhatsApp/Media/Whatsapp Images\IMG-20211031-WA0050.jpg': No such file or directory
```

I saw other questions on the same theme here on stack overflow and noticed that the problem could be the length of the path. But if I run:

```
D:\Android\media\com.whatsapp>adb pull "/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20211031-WA0026.jpg" "./WhatsApp/Media/Whatsapp Images"
```

(so by changing only 2 numbers and maintaining the same dimensions of the path) it works for the file.

Some other informations:

- the file exists (searched both in the phone and with adb shell)
- the command that gives me the error works fine if I run it with a parent folder as target (for isntance it works both in ./WhatsApp and ./WhatsApp/Media)
- the phone is redmi 10 (don't think its useful but who knows)
- D:/ unit is an sd card plugged in my pc
- I am running cmd as administrator as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11519988

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the command works if you remove the local target directory (so just specify the remote path)? Because the error message reads like the problem is on Windows side. And the local Windows path `"./WhatsApp/Media/Whatsapp Images"` you use looks wrong as you use `/` instead of ``\``.

Comment: @Robert I cd's in the WhatsApp Images folder and executed the command without the target parameter. It still give the same error. Furthermore I've put the / instead the \ when the path weren't recognized (supposing some unicode escape rule or something). In theory it isn't a problem,